# Determining a "spaghetti boundary" 0f formal $n$-squares

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Consider a *formal $n$-square*, i.e., the set $\{ 0, 1, .., n-1 \}^2$ of *positions* (column number, row number) of a square $n$-matrix. A *cyclic rotation* of the $j$-th row $\{ (i,j) : i = 0 .. n-1 \}$ by an integer amount $r$ maps $(i,j)$ to $(i + r \text{ mod } n, j)$ for each $i$. A *horizontal move* consists of a cyclic rotation of some rows by some amount (which may be different for each involved row).

Let $S$ be a set of $n$ positions, distributed over a number of rows. The more rows containing positions of $S$, the less elements on individual rows. The "spaghetti effect" occurs when it is possible to apply a horizontal move shifting the positions of $S$ into all different columns. Considering a horizontal move as "exercising pressure" on $S$ and moving positions row by row into distinct columns as "crumbling", some intuition gets explained: a set of $n$ positions involving many rows is like a string of spaghetti, having small (rows) sections. With the appropriate pressure, it should crumble completely.

The *spaghetti boundary* of a formal $n$-square is the least number $s(n)$ such that all sets of $n$ positions involving more than $s(n)$ rows can have their row sections moved apart. In my paper "shuffled equi-$n$-squares", available at

http://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02325

a method was developed to estimate spaghetti boundaries for various sizes $n$. The method relies on results about rotating sets apart in a regular $n$-gon. The results for $8 \leq n \leq 50$ can be found in table 5 of the cited paper.

Only a few values are proven sharp. They are listed here in the format $(n, s(n))$ for $n \geq 4$:
$$(4,2), (5,2), (6,3), (7,3), (8,4), (9,5), (12,7).$$
For $n = 2, 3$ the spaghetti effect occurs all the time whence $s(2) = s(3) = 0$. For a few other $n$ we have a value that is proven sharp up to one unit.

Question. Find sharp spaghetti boundaries for other $n$.

Added 04/29/2017: s(10)=5 is sharp too.

Added 19/05/2017: I finally managed to write a (rather lengthy) inductive proof showing that Hagen von Eitzen's proposal for $s(n)$ is correct for all $n$. I don't see a way to attach a pdf-file here.

Comment: So a different formulation would be: Given $m$ regular $n$-gons such that $n$ of the $mn$ vertices are marked (at least one for each $n$-gon), it may or may not be possible to rotate (but not reflect) and overlay the $n$-gons to obtain an $n$-gon with all vertices coloured. Let $s(n)$ be the maximal $m$ for which such a constellation exists for which one cannot achieve that all vertices are coloured?

Comment: ... So it seems that a search for $s(10)$ can be performed by throwing some (but not very much) CPU at it?

Comment: .. without reading the results in your paper, it is clear that $s(10)\ge 5$ (pick five rows with each having two even positions occupied), and $s(10)<7$ ($10=3+2+1+1+1+1+1$: the three-rwo can block at most $6$ of ten possible positions for the two-row; $10=2+2+2+1+1+1+1$: the first two-rows can block at most $8$ positions for the last two-rpw). So what about $6$? $10=4+2+1+1+1+1$ and $10=3+3+1+1+1+1$ can be solved by the same argument; $10=3+2+2+1+1+1$ requires a few more thoughts how the two-rows can interfere, but I think can be easily dismissed; only $10=2+2+2+1+1$ I'd test systematically

Comment: The table in my paper gives an estimated spaghetti boundary s(10) = 6. In my personal notes I see that I considered rotating four pairs apart, which is probably what you propose on the last line (with three 2's).  A few years ago I ran a C-program with n up to 30 something on the problem of rotating pairs apart in an $n$-gon (see my question on "how many clock hands".  If I can trust my short notes, four worked fine but five pairs can fail. This would mean that 5 rows of 2 can fail the spaghetti effect and s(10)=5 is sharp.

Comment: I just finished my unpolished code and it produces the sequence $0,0,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,8,9,10,10,11,12$ (which is not in OEIS), and now begins to become really slow while computing $s(20)$ ... Is it clear that $n\ge4\implies s(n)le s(n+1)\le s(n)+1$?

Comment: ... and this looks suspiciously like $s(n)\approx \frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}n$, doesn't it?

Comment: I withdraw my guess about the golden ratio - after all there is a simple bound $s(n)\ge n-2\lceil\sqrt n\rceil+2$.

Comment: @Hagen: your sequence improves some of my sp-values. What exactly have you been testing? When using number partitions, the ones can largely be neglected as they can always be rotated in the leftover columns. This can help to stretch your program to larger n.

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem.** Let $n\ge 4$. Then
$$ s(n)=n+2-\min_{ab\ge n}(a+b)=n+2-\lceil\sqrt n\,\rceil-\left\lceil\frac{n}{\lceil\sqrt n\,\rceil}\right\rceil.$$
*Proof.*
First we show the second equality: If we want to minimize $a+b$ under the condition $ab\ge n$ (and wlog. $a\ge b$), we certainly need $a\ge\sqrt n$. And if $a=\lceil\sqrt n\,\rceil+r$ with $r\ge 0$, then we need $b\ge\frac na$, i.e., we need to choose $r$ to minimize $r+\left\lceil\frac{n}{\lceil\sqrt n\,\rceil+r}\right\rceil$, but increasing $r$ by one decreases the second summand by at most one, so that the minimum is attained already for $r=0.

Next we show $s(n)\ge m$ if $m=n-a-b+2$ with $ab\ge n\ge a+b$ (and so $m\ge2$). We may assume wlog. that $a(b-1)<n$.
Let $$\begin{align}A_1&=\{0,1,\ldots,a-1\},\\A_2&=\{0,a,2a,\ldots,(b-1)a\},\\ A_k&=\{0\}\qquad\text{for }3\le k\le m.\end{align}$$ (All viewed as subsets of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$). Then $\sum_{k=1}^m|A_k|=a+b+(m-2)=n$. Assume there are integers $c_1,\ldots,c_m$ such that $\bigcup(A_i+c_i)=\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, or equivalently $(A_i+c_i)\cap (A_j+c_j)=\emptyset$ for $i\ne j$. We may assume wlog $c_1=a(b-1)$. Then $0\le c_2<a$ leads to a conflict because $(b-1)a\in A_2$, $a\le c_2<2a$ does the same because $(b-2)a\in A_2$, and so on, so that $0\le c_2<ab$ leads to a conflict. By assumption, this covers all residue classes $\bmod n$. Hence $(c_1,\ldots,c_m)$ as desired cannot exist, thus showing $s(n)\ge m$ and ultimately
$$s(n)\ge  n+2-\lceil\sqrt n\,\rceil-\left\lceil\frac{n}{\lceil\sqrt n\,\rceil}\right\rceil.$$

The other direction follows from the claim below, where we work with $d=n-m$ and thus without all one-element sets $A_i$, which never pose a problem. $\square$

**Claim.** 
Let $n\ge 4$ and let $d$ be a non-negative integer $<\lceil\sqrt n\,\rceil-\left\lceil\frac{n}{\lceil\sqrt n\,\rceil}\right\rceil$.
Let $k\in\Bbb N$ and $a_1\ge a_2\ge \ldots\ge a_k\ge 2$ and $a_1+\ldots+a_k\le k+d$. Then for any choice of sets $A_1,\ldots,A_k\subseteq\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ with $|A_i|=a_i$, there exist integers $c_1,\ldots,c_k$ with $A_i+c_i\cap A_j+c_j=\emptyset$.

*Proof* [by induction on $k$].
The case $k=1$ is trivial.
Assume $k\ge2$ and the claim is already correct for smaller $k$.
Let $A_1,\ldots,A_k$ as in the claim be given.
From $a_1+\ldots+a_{k-1}\le(k-1)+d$ and the induction hypothesis, we find suitable $c_1,\ldots,c_{k-1}$. Of the $n$ possible choices for $c_k\bmod n$, this prohibits at most
$$\tag1 a_k\cdot(a_1+\ldots+a_{k-1})\le a_k(k+d-a_k)\le\frac1k\cdot\frac{k-1}{k}\cdot (k+d)^2$$
(using $ka_k\le a_1+\ldots+a_k\le k+d$ and that$x\mapsto x(a-x)$ is increasing on $[0,\tfrac a2]$). 
As $k\le (a_1-1)+\ldots+(a_k-1)\le d<2\sqrt n$, this is $<\frac{4n}k$, which already $<n$ and hence sufficient if $k\ge4$.
If $k=3$, our estimate $(1)$ is $< \frac29\cdot 4n<n$ and we are done again. 
Remains the case $k=2$.
But then the conditions of the claim give us
$$a_1+a_2<\lceil\sqrt n\,\rceil-\left\lceil\frac{n}{\lceil\sqrt n\,\rceil}\right\rceil=\min_{ab\ge n}(a+b)$$
so that we conclude $a_1a_2<n$, i.e., again there are less than $n$ choices prohibited. $\square$

Comment: Beautiful. In the proof of the Claim I recognize many ingredients of my original proof of lemma 3.11. But you have dealt far more cleverly with numbers and formulae than I did. In this way, you avoided some restrictions and complications that I met with. I.'m going to check the consequences of  the strengthened result.  I'll inform you soon.

Comment: On second reading, it seems to me that you run into a similar problem as I did in the proof of my lemma 3.11. After you get k <= d < 2 sqrt(n) you want (1) < n. Now d<ceil(sqrt(n))+ceil(n/ceil(sqrt(n))). With n=127 the maximal d is then 22 and for k=3 formula (1) equals  138.8888889 >127. The "4n" is wrong in your computation.